# android continuously downloading image from web server

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, imagedownload

I want to download an image from the web server for every 1 second. Can some one tell me the  best approach to achieve this. Currently, i am thinking to use Executer class but i am not sure whether that would be a better approach or not. Please help me.

Comment: You are aware what that means for network traffic and battery life?

Comment: i have a touch panel connected to a machine. An user can control the machine from that touch panel. The web server running in the touch panel will be having screen shot of the panel taken for every 1 sec. My goal is to download that image and to show in an image view.

Answer (score 0):

to perform this you might need use asynctask. this is my idea, retrieve all the image url from the server,then manipulate the url. you can use library such as android smart android view to display the image from the server just by only providing the image url.

android smart android view:-
http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/